# wait for signalr methods to finish

Tags: angularjs, promise, signalr

I have three methods:

```
myHub.server.getColumnSettings().done(function (result) {
    if (result) {
        //Do stuff with result
    }
});
myHub.server.getDefaultGroupedBy().done(function(result) {
    if (result) {
        //Do stuff with result      
    }
});

function init() {
    //Do more stuff
}
```

I would like getColumnsSettings to finish, and after that I want getDefaultGroupedBy to finish, and after that init().

I tried following, but it didn't work..

```
var defer = $q.defer();

defer.promise
.then(function() {
    myHub.server.getColumnSettings().done(function (result) {
        if (result) {
            //Do stuff with result
        }
    });
})
.then(function() {
    myHub.server.getDefaultGroupedBy().done(function(result) {
        if (result) {
            //Do stuff with result      
        }
    });
})
.then(function() {
    init();
});

defer.resolve();
```

Comment: Do `getColumnSettings()`/`getDefaultGroupedBy()`/`done()` return promises?

Comment: `then` doesn't magically detect asynchronous things in its callbacks. You need to throw it a bone: `return` a promise, otherwise it can't wait for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The promise chaining you are looking for only works if you are returning a promise again in any then block. If you don't return a promise, the then handle will immediately return undefined and subsequent handlers will be called instantly. If however, you return a promise, the next `then` handler will wait for this promise to be resolved and so on.

Also, it looks like your methods `getColumnSettings` and `getDefaultGroupedBy` are already returning promises, so instead of wrapping them in a deferred object you might as well use them right away. If, however, you do not exactly know, how the promises returned by SignalR behave, you can still wrap them using the Angular's $q api.

You should be able to write something like:

```
var columnSettingsPromise = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
  myHub.server.getColumnSettings().done(function (result) {
    if (result) {
      // Do stuff with result
      // resolve the promise with the obtained result (will be passed to the then handler)
      resolve(result);
      // we are returning a promise in this function which will be resolved at some point
    } else {
        reject(new Error('no column settings loaded'));
    }
  });
});
// wait until the column settings have been retrieved
columnSettingsPromise.
then(function(columnSettings) {
  // return a new promise, the next then handler will wait for this promise
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    myHub.server.getDefaultGroupedBy().done(function(result) {
      if (result) {
        // do stuff with the result
        resolve(result);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('no default grouped by data loaded'));
      }
    });
  });
})
// the next handler will only be called after the promise for getDefaultGroupedBy data has been resolved
// as soon as that's the case, just call init
.then(init);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.. But how would it look if I wrap it in a deferred object?

Comment: Tried this, at `.then()` the defaultGroupedBy parameter wasn't the result from `getDefaultGroupedBy()` instead it was the result from `getColumnSettings()`

Comment: hmm .. then it might be an issue with the kind of promise that is being returned from `myHub.server.getColumnSettings()`. I'll update the answer to make use of the deferred api, that should do the trick.